# after upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 cannot boot with linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, boot, upgrade, kernel

After upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04, I cannot boot with linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae: process gets frozen in a xubuntu initialization screen (I had qimo installed).

If I try the recovery mode (with the same Linux version), booting freezes after this message:

Begin: Mounting root file system.

If in grub menu I choose Previous Linux versions, I can boot using Linux 2.6.32-41-generic-pae. But once logged in, some things don't seem to work (apt-get update fails, update manager fails, HID menu does not provide suggestions...) (to be honest, I have no idea whether this is part of the bigger issue)

Reading in [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) through apparently similar problems, I decided to follow some advices: got boot-repair and run it. The problem remains & I got this [report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/978851/).

I also run as root in terminal

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and this is what I got:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae

cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/sda1

cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab

/tmp/mkinitramfs_EIDlHy/scripts/classmate-bottom/45xconfig: 9: .: Can't open /scripts/casper-functions
```

What else? My pc is Intel® Core™ i7 CPU 870 @ 2.93GHz × 8, graphs is GeForce 8400 GS/PCIe/SSE2, memory is 7,8 GiB.

I have two questions: Is this a bug in the newest kernel I should report? Is there anything I can do appart from a fresh install?

Comment: There are issues with upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 and clearly warned in the release notes to post pone it.Please read this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop

Comment: @beeju thanks for the link, I must admit I did read the warning only after doing the upgrade! Oh well, it won't happen again...

Answer (score 2):

Based on this upstream Debian bug report I'd say the two cryptsetup warning messages are not related to the cause of the boot failure.

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=641662

There are suggestions that removing the canonical-census package fixes the issue about not being able to open /scripts/casper-functions

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9741353

Answer (score 0):

Your report shows that your Ubuntu partition ends far from the start of the disk:

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5002ABYS-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  490GB  490GB   primary   ext4            boot
```

So you may need this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998257

Answer (score -1):

After some time on it, I think I can now partially answer the minor issues:

> HUD menu does not provide suggestions...

I have been able to replicate in an ASUS EeePC T101MT the HUD problem. I started from fresh install 10.04.2 from USB, updated using Synaptic, then upgraded to 12.04. HUD would not work properly. This looks to me like a bug. I will report it as bug if it has not been reported (any help/info appreciated)

> I cannot boot with linux 3.2.0-24-generic-pae

I could not replicate the boot problem with the ASUS, so really no clues there. It could be machine specific, it could be software I had installed...

> a xubuntu initialization screen (I had qimo installed)

qimo and Xfce do not play any role here: HUD problem takes place if I install qimo before upgrading and also if I do not install it. And no boot problem in the ASUS regardless of qimo.

> Is there anything I can do appart from a fresh install?

Surely a 12.04 fresh intall and everything works in the ASUS. So, if you really want to go 12.04, as @beeju said, please first read

[wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop)